# Proxying spark UI rewriting urls

Tags: apache-spark, nginx

I'm running spark on a private network, so worker ips, etc. are in the 10.4.x.x range. The worker ips aren't fixed, and if new workers spin up, they get new ips. Spark UI has a web interface that allows me to explore jobs, nodes, etc., but all the urls are to the private network. Is it possible to somehow rewrite the urls so that the UI works as expected from outside the private network? I'm thinking something with nginx might do the trick.